# how to pass and receive a parameter using link-to from ember js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, link-to

I have on my page a list of clients (only names) and when I click on each one of them, I want to open a new page called 'clientdetails' in which I get the details of the client besides its name (I have an address and an age) ;

What I have so far is something like this :

```
{{#each model as |client|}}
    <p> {{#link-to "clientdetails"}} {{client.name}} {{/link-to}}
    </p>
  {{/each}}
```

How should I pass client.address and client.age to clientdetails and display them accordingly in the clientdetails page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/templates/links/

I guess you could create a route in your `route.js` to route to your client details:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('clients', function(){
    this.route('clientdetails', { path: '/:client_id' });
  });
});
```

In your `template` (to link with your client details):

```
{{#each model as |client|}}
    <p> {{#link-to "clientdetails" client}} {{client.name}} {{/link-to}}
    </p>
 {{/each}}
```

Last, create a template `clientdetails` where you show your client details:

```
<p>{{model.name}}</p>
<p>{{model.address}}</p>
<p>{{model.age}}</p>
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Keep in mind that passing the model to link-to will cause that route's model hook to be ignored, if you do want the model hook to be triggered pass the model id instead (client.id)

Comment: @Kitler still usually the right way is to pass the model itself, because a re-fetch is not necessary.

Comment: Godo point @Lux , so do you think that the right way  is {{#link-to "clientdetails" client}}, right?

Comment: Yes! The only reason to not directly pass the model is when you do complex things in the `model` hook. Never for the standard implementation.
Its just important to understand how it works.